# swagger ui with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, swagger-ui

I need specific role to access swagger ui

snippet to access swagger-ui with role 2 ( tried following with no joy)

```
http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ROLE1")
                    .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/info/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ROLE2")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/swagger-ui.html", true)
                .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html")
```

Permit all  works - this checks all the resources are granted access

```
http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ROLE1")
                    .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/info/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/swagger-ui.html", true)
                .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html")
```

there is in memory user for role2

```
auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1").password("userpassword").roles("ROLE2");;
```

but when I login it doesnt bring up the swagger-ui , is there any thing missing            ?

permitAll does show the swagger-ui
any help appreciated

I tried

```
http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers(
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/swagger-resources",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/webjars/**", "/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ROLE1")
                    .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/info/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/webjars/**").hasRole("ROLE2")
```

Comment: Are you getting a 403 or a 404 ?. Can you post your swagger configuration ?

Comment: this is 6 months old questions, it will take time to reinstate this project, not sure  when as this is not a priority at the moment